# NameError: global name 'variable' is not defined python

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, syntax-error

I'm working on a project and this error keeps showing up:

```
class PRNG:
    def __init__(self):
    # parameters
    # P-256 prime
    self.p=115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951

    self.a=self.p-3
    self.b=41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291
    self.E=curve(self.a,self.b,self.p)

    self.E.n=115792089210356248762697446949407573529996955224135760342422259061068512044369

    self.P=point(0,46263761741508638697010950048709651021688891777877937875096931459006746039284)
    self.k=183521403747637560534595403690771364941493702673414885451510208165414833985
    self.Q=mult(self.k,self.P,self.E)

    self.t=bytes_to_int(os.urandom(32)) # initial seed
    #print self.t
    self.output_length=240
    self.truncate_length=16

    def function_attack(self, nbytes, predicted_state):
        calls = ((nbytes*8-1)/self.output_length)+1
        out = ''
        for i in xrange(calls):
            tP=mult(predicted_state,self.P,self.E)
            s=tP.x
            sQ=mult(s,self.Q,self.E)
            r=sQ.x
            r_out=r % (2**self.output_length)
            self.t=s
            out = out + int_to_bytes(r_out, self.output_length/8)
        return out[:nbytes]

def function(self, nbytes):
        calls = ((nbytes*8-1)/self.output_length)+1
        out = ''
        for i in xrange(calls):
            tP=mult(self.t,self.P,self.E)
            s=tP.x
            sQ=mult(s,self.Q,self.E)
            r=sQ.x
            r_out=r % (2**self.output_length)
            self.t=s
            out = out + int_to_bytes(r_out, self.output_length/8)
        return out[:nbytes]
```

The first method is being called in a separate file and the output is always the following(regardless if I change the name of the local variable **calls**):

```
File "C:\file1.py", line 32, in <module>
    prng = PRNG()
  File "C:\file_where_error_occurs.py", line 286, in __init__
    for i in xrange(calls):
NameError: global name 'calls' is not defined
```

What is python doing?

Comment: what is PRNG? it seems like we are missing some critical information here ,,, please post an example that we can run and will give the same error

Comment: So, I see I have received a down-vote which, let's say, it may be fine(since I haven't programmed in python before) but I am more surprised about the vote to close question. @CloseVoter. Please state a valid reason as to why this question is off-topic.

Comment: Try to `print calls` before using it. You might be surprised...

Comment: @ Joran Beasley The class in which the methods are defined

Comment: Your error is coming from `__init__` yet that is the only part of the code we can't see.

Comment: @Sebi what does `*` have to do with this question? why is it mentioned in the title?  please post an example that we can run to demonstrate the issue .... I would suspect you are doing `for i in xrange(calls)` in your init function but there is no `calls` variabl;e there

Comment: @Joran Beasley It's meant as a wild card meaning that for any variable name chosen for calls the same error output is given. No, variable calls is local to the respective methods. It is not being used anywhere else.

Comment: @Sebi that is not the meaning in python ... that will make your question more confusing and likely to be closed.  furthermore the traceback you posted does not match the code you posted ... this makes it more likely this question will be closed ... as it stands no one can answer your question except to tell you that your variable is not defined at the time you are trying to access it

Comment: The code you posted will not produce the error that you are getting.  Your `__init__` does not use `for i in xrange(calls):`.  It looks like you may have issues with indentation.

Comment: @ Joran Beasley I've changed the title.The __init__ section has been added. The only inconsistencies are the line numbers.

Comment: Are you using an editor that understands python indentation rules?

Comment: no its more than line numbers ... the code posted has indentation errors not name errors ... as mentioned if you cannot post a small code example that can be copied and pasted to generate the same error you are unlikely to recieve any answer, let alone a correct one

Answer (score 0):

you have indentation errors ... this is typically caused by mixing tabs and spaces ... most decent editors can fix this for you easily ... to see your indentation errors run your program as

```
python -tt my_program.py
```

Comment: I've rewritten the functions and they were indeed indentation problems. I am using notepad++ and ,visually, the cod is valid. Unfortunately now there is another one: AttributeError: PRNG instance has no attribute 'get_randomness'. It seems that the method is no longer in the class. I have run the above command. No errors were shown apart from the one mentioned above in the comment.

Comment: `def randomness(self,whatever)` is unindented to the global level indent it to the inner class method level .... and use an IDE that will manage your spaces/tabs for you (like pycharm or eclipse)... also if this answers your original question you should probably accept it ...

Comment: It is indented to the inner class method.

Comment: then you still have tabs mixed with spaces ... run the command I listed

Comment: @Sebi: There are tabs at the beginning of the lines containing the `calls = ((...` which follow the ones that start with `def function...` (which are OK).

Comment: I have downloaded pycharm and indented all code. Now this error occurs: AttributeError: PRNG instance has no attribute 'get_randomness'

Comment: @Joran Beasley It showed the line where the indentation was off but any edit on the given line(tabs, spaces) were of little use in fixing the issue. So, I cannot accept the suggested answer yet.